# Why does UIStackView keep collapsing label?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview, ios-autolayout

I've got a label and a button embedded in a horizontal stack view - a label for temperature and a button for °C/°F (which highlights the users preference in bold; when they tap the button the preference switches and the temperature label updates).

It's fine when °C is in bold, but when I change the preference and °F becomes bold, the button collapses to only say °...°F. The stack view is distributed to Fill. I think the horizontal content compression resistance priority of the label should be higher to prevent it collapsing, but this doesn't change anything (I tried setting it to 759) so I'm at a loss as to what to search/change to correct this.

Is anyone able to give me a heads up as to what might be happening please?

[image: The correct appearance for the label and button.]

[image: The collapsed appearance.]

Many thanks in advance!

Edit: There are no other constraints between the label and button within the UIStackView. The stack view is in a vertical stack view with a City label - see image.[image: The two stack views.] 
That vertical stack view is pinned to the top and bottom of the screen.

[image: Xcode overview of stack views.]

Second edit: When the button is pressed I perform the following:

```
@IBAction func updateTemperaturePreference(_ sender: TemperaturePreferenceButton) {
    temperaturePreference = (temperaturePreference == .celsius) ? .fahrenheit: .celsius
}
```

temperaturePreference has a didSet on it, so that when it changes it calls updateStyle on the custom button:

```
   temperaturePreferenceButton.updateStyle(temperaturePreference: temperaturePreference)
```

And here's the code for my custom button:

```
class TemperaturePreferenceButton: UIButton {

let title = UnitTemperature.celsius.symbol + "/" + UnitTemperature.fahrenheit.symbol + "Some more text"

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupButton()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupButton()
}

private func setupButton() {
    setTitle(title, for: .normal)
}

func updateStyle(temperaturePreference: TemperaturePreference) {
        switch temperaturePreference {
        case .celsius:
            let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: 2)
            titleLabel?.attributedText = attributedString(from: title, boldRange: range)

        case .fahrenheit:
            let range = NSRange(location: 3, length: 2)
            titleLabel?.attributedText = attributedString(from: title, boldRange: range)
    }
    setNeedsDisplay()
}

private func attributedString(from string: String, boldRange: NSRange?) -> NSAttributedString {
    let fontSize = UIFont.systemFontSize
    let attributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: fontSize),
        NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.blue
    ]
    let nonBoldAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize),
        NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.red
    ]
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: nonBoldAttributes)
    if let range = boldRange {
        attributedString.setAttributes(attributes, range: range)
    }
    return attributedString
}
```

}

Comment: Could you share all other constraints

Comment: Apologies for late reply - I've now added further details, but let me know if need anything else!

Comment: @ADB - show the code you are using to change the button title/

Comment: @DonMag I've added this to the question - many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
titleLabel?.attributedText = attributedString(from: title, boldRange: range)
```

Doesn't let UIKit and auto-layout fully handle the change. Try using this instead:

```
setAttributedTitle(attributedString(from: title, boldRange: range), for: .normal)
```

That *should* take care of the issue. If you still see problems, add `.sizeToFit()`:

```
setAttributedTitle(attributedString(from: title, boldRange: range), for: .normal)
sizeToFit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
        let attrTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "°C/°F")
        attrTitle.beginEditing()
        let range = toggle == true ? NSRange(location: 0, length: 2) : NSRange(location: 3, length: 2)
        attrTitle.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font,
                               value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold),
                               range: range)
        attrTitle.endEditing()
        sender.setAttributedTitle(attrTitle, for: .normal)
```

[image]